# how save from multi checkbox item with codeiginiter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, checkbox

I'am have assigment scholl project with codeigniter, i want to save a value form many checkbox item with codeigniter with simple script this is my script:
my controller :

```
 class Item extends CI_Controller{  
     function save() { 
        $item1 = $this->input->post('item1');
        $item2 = $this->input->post('item2');
          ...............
        $item100 = $this->input->post('item100');       
        $this->item_model->save($item1,$item2,..........$item100);        
      } 
}
```

and this my model:

```
class Item_model extends CI_Model{
     function save($item1,$item2,............,$item100) { 
        $data= array( 'item1'=> $item1,'item2'=> $item2,......... ,'item100'=> $item100);
        $this->db->insert('tbl_item',$data);
    }
 }
```

can someone help me ,how to simple it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Change the name of Checkbox like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]">
```

Then Change Save code like

```
$items = $this->input->post('item');
$loopcount = sizeof($items);
for($i =0 ; $i<= $loopcount; $i++)
{
    //your save code here
     $this->item_model->save($items[$i]);
}
```

Comment: greatfully , thanks a lot, this is a complete i'am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Use array as name of your all checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="input[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="input[]">
.
.
<input type="checkbox" name="input[]"><!--all 100 checkbox-->
```

So you can get array as input

```
$items = $this->input->post('item');
```

So you can simply call `save` function with one parameter

```
$this->item_model->save($items);
```

> **Note**: Request only get value of checked checkbox.

Comment: yes, i do as your sugges change name of checkbox for array "checkbox[]" , and add more scrpit from @Nabeel Qadri,